# how to compare values in an existing dictionary and update the dictionary back to a file?

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I am making an utility of sorts with dictionary. What I am trying to achieve is this:

for each XML file that I parse, the existing dictionary is loaded from a file (output.dict) and compared/updated for the current key and stored back along with existing values. I tried with has_key() and attributerror, it does not work.

Since I trying one file at a time, it creates multiple dictionaries and am unable to compare. This is where I am stuck.

```
def createUpdateDictionary(servicename, xmlfile):
   dictionary = {}
   if path.isfile == 'output.dict':
       dictionary.update (eval(open('output.dict'),'r'))


   for event, element in etree.iterparse(xmlfile):


      dictionary.setdefault(servicename, []).append(element.tag)

   f = open('output.dict', 'a')
   write_dict = str(dictionary2)
   f.write(write_dict)
   f.close()
```

(here the servicename is nothing but a split '.' of xmlfile which forms the key and values are nothing by the element's tag name)

Comment: ugh don't use eval. Have you considered a real serialization format, such as JSON?

Comment: hey, i haven't used JSON. I am wondering if dictionary is the best method to do it.

Comment: It isn't, because it introduces security holes when you try to eval the string representation of a dictionary :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def createUpdateDictionary(servicename, xmlfile):
   dictionary = {}
   if path.isfile == 'output.dict':
       dictionary.update (eval(open('output.dict'),'r'))
```

There is a typo, as the `'r'` argument belongs to `open()`, not `eval()`.  Furthermore, you cannot evaluate a file object as returned by `open()`, you have to `read()` the contents first.

```
   f = open('output.dict', 'a')
   write_dict = str(dictionary2)
   f.write(write_dict)
   f.close()
```

Here, you are appending the string representation to the file.  The string representation is not guaranteed to represent the dictionary completely.  It is meant to be readable by humans to allow inspection, not to persist the data.

Moreover, since you are using `'a'` to append the data, you are storing multiple copies of the updated dictionary in the file.  Your file might look like:

```
{}{"foo": []}{"foo": [], "bar":[]}
```

This is clearly not what you want; you won't even by able to `eval()` it later (syntax error!).

Since `eval()` will execute arbitrary Python code, it is considered *evil* and you really should not use it for object serialization.  Either use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html), which is the standard way of serialization in Python, or use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), which is a human-readable standard format supported by other languages as well.

```
import json

def createUpdateDictionary(servicename, xmlfile):
    with open('output.dict', 'r') as fp:
        dictionary = json.load(fp)

    # ... process XML, update dictionary ...

    with open('output.dict', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(dictionary, fp)
```

Comment: Hey, JSON is classic. it did the trick. I am trying to process dictionary and XML, otherwise it simply appends to existing dictionary. Will put my code back for others once I am done with it. Thanks a lot Ferdinand